# Retrieve Session variables into ASP.NET MVC 4 (razor, view)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session-variables

I wrote many websites with PHP. Now, I have to create website with ASP MVC 4 (c#) and I am stuck with Sessions.

I.E. the user should go to login page, enter his/her login and password. If they are correct, in controller, I set the session with UserId, like this:

```
Session["UserId"] = 10
```

This UserId value is used for showing PartialViews (login form or (after login) some application menus). How can I get this UserId inside Razor view ?

After this in View:

```
if (Session.UserId == 10) { @Html.Partial("LoggedMenu") }
```

i've got exception with StackOverflow. :/

Comment: Can you add an ASP or similar tag please?

Comment: Seems like in this scenario you should not be using session. UserId should be part of the model (or if not part of the model you could use ViewBag) returned to the view by the controller.

Comment: **Session's are evil**, specially if you're using Cloud Hosting... be aware!

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: Did you try using the same syntax for Session in the view as in the controller?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you're doing it wrong...

`Session[<item name>]` returns a string, you should compare with a string as well, or cast it, so, either `(int)Session["UserId"] == 10` or `Session["UserId"] = "10"`.

you also are invoking a property that does not exist `Session.UserId` will not exist as `Session` is like an NameValueCollection, you call it by request it's item name.

at the end, you should write

```
@if (Session["UserId"] == "10") { 
    Html.Partial("LoggedMenu"); 
}
```

You say your are learning, so I would like to point out 2 quick things:

- You should take advantage of the ASP.NET MVC Course that is available for free in the home page http://asp.net/mvc (right side when you read "Essential Videos")
- Create an MVC3 project and see how they do it as it comes ready out of the box with Membership

Comment: I believe `Session[<item name>]` returns an Object not a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
@if (Session["UserId"] != null && Session["UserId"] == 10 ) { 
Html.Partial("LoggedMenu"); 
}
```

Apart from that: for identity management better use the out of the box [membership system](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-simplemembership-in-asp.net-mvc-4.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Below is a an example:

Controller:

```
    if (Session["pageInitCounter"] == null)
    {
        Session["pageInitCounter"] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int counter = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pageInitCounter"]);
        counter++;
        Session["pageInitCounter"] = counter;
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.Hidden("pageInitCounter", Session["pageInitCounter"])
```

Javascript:

```
alert($("#pageInitCounter").val());
```

Comment: It works, but why "@Html.Hidden("pageInitCounter", Session["pageInitCounter"])" , can we just call the Session directly in alert?

Comment: alert() is client side javascript.  You need to write the asp server var to the page for javascript to be able to reference it. Flea does this by calling the @Html.Hidden helper.